# I can not add MySql Data Provider to Visual Studio 2012

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, sqldatasource, mysql-connector

I want to create an .edmx file to my .net project. My database is MySql. As you can see the picture below, there is no MySql provider however I give the refference about MySql. I install  MySqlConnector for c# but the same result.
Do you have any suggestion?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because of MySql Connector version. I installed an older version and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

version 6.6.6 worked 
Give a try.